# List to JSON string with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot converter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a service that produces HTML pages via Thymeleaf templates. In one of those templates I would like to have an HTML attribute as a JSON string. The related Object in my context is an `ArrayList<String>`. Without doing anything the output would be `"[item1, item2]"` but I want `"["random","stuff"]"`.

I've read about `Converter` and `Formatter` and I thought that was the way to go. But I cannot get my conversion system to work.

Here is my custom `Converter`:

```java
public class ListConverter implements Converter(ArrayList<String>, String {
  public String convert (ArrayList<String> source) {
    return new JSONArray(source).toString();
  }
}
```

The main class looks like

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TheApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PageServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public ListConverter listConverter() {
    return new ListConverter();
  }

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter( listConverter() );
  }
}
```

Finally the Thymeleaf template looks like

```
<some-webcomponent xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    th:attrappend="tags=${data.tags} ...">
</some-webcomponent>
```

So `tags` is my `ArrayList<String>`. I have also tried forcing the conversion with `${{data.tags}}` or with `${#conversions.convert(data.tags, 'String'}`but the only this is does is turn `"[item1, item2]"` to `"item1,item2"`.

Doing `tags=${new org.json.JSONArray(data.tags)}` works but I could like to have that elsewhere and probably not only for `ArrayList<String>`.

So my questions are :

- is this possible at all ?
- are `Converter` the way to go ?
- what am I missing with the configuration ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, it works using List instead of ArrayList.  Also, I would get rid of the addFormatters method.  You just need the bean declaration.

Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TheApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PageServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Converter<List<String>, String> converter() {
    return new Converter<List<String>, String>() {
      public String convert(List<String> source) {
        return new JSONArray(source).toString();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Thymeleaf (double bracket for tags)

```
<some-webcomponent xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    th:attrappend="tags=${{data.tags}} ...">
</some-webcomponent>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)