# Is there a way to inline a Spring MVC model attribute in JSON in thymeleaf for an html attribute?

Tags: html, json, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Okay, So, I have a model object that we will call Station, with a list of codes associated.

```java
class Station {
   public List<String> codes;
}
```

I have a controller method which render a view showing the list of a station.

```java
class StationController {

    @Autowired
    private StationService stationService;
    @GetMapping()
    public String showAllStations(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("stations", stationService.getAllStations())
        return "stationsView"
    }
}
```

Here is my template

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body> 
        <div th:each="station : ${stations}" th:text="${station.codes}">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, let's say my first station as two codes, CD1 et CD2. The rendered html will be the following :

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body> 
        <div>[CD1, CD2]</div>
        ...Skipping the additional divs.
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to render the codes as a JSON array ? I know thymeleaf can do it in javascript, using inline.

For example,

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var data = [[${renter.sabreCodes}]];
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

will be rendered as

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var data = ["CD1","CD2"];
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

So I  would want the same result for an attribute value.

Of course, I have a lot of workaround for this, but I would want to know if these workaround are needed, or if it just me who don't know how to get straight to the point.

Comment: Did you check the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067604/list-to-json-string-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot-converter ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Seems like converter is the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List to JSON string with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067604/list-to-json-string-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot-converter)

Comment: in fact, not necessarily : Sometimes I want list as is, sometimes as json list. I will check other solutions.